# JSHint Sublime Text - "esnext": in jshintrc not stopping error for const

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jshint

I don't know if I'm missing something (likely) but I tried "esnext": true and "esnext": false in my jshintrc file, but I am still getting error in Sublime Text when I try to use 'const' instead of 'var'.

Comment: The code works. But I'd like to stop the error in Sublime Text.

Comment: Is the name of your file `.jshintrc` or is it `jshintrc`? It should be the first one. If that is already the name of your file, please update your post with the entire contents of your `.jshintrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

In your Home directory (`~`) ensure there is a file named `.jshirc`

The contents of that file should have, at a minimum:

`{
"esnext" : true
}`

For more information see [.jshirc examples](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc)